# Generate List of created Task Lists

Tags: list, list-form, task-list

I have two lists and I am trying to use a workflow to create a third:

List 1: (New-Hire List)
A list of New Hires that contains several fields to record their onboarding. 
One of the fields is "Onboarding Phase" that can be set to Phase 1,2,3, etc. When the Onboarding Phase is set to 2 or 3, and the New Hire form is saved, a workflow executes that creates a Task-List in a separate sub-site.

List 2: (Task-List)
This task list is titled with the New Hire's Name. I created this because I did not know how to make a list of lists in SharePoint.

How do I create a workflow to generate a third list or a view that lists all of the newly created task-lists on the sub-site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new Task List for every New Hire, you should have a single `Task List` that has a [Lookup Column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) pointing to the `New Hire List`. Then every Task you create with the workflow should have this column's value for that Task set to the New Hire Item you are currently processing.

If you wanted to have tasks for different phases, you could add a [Choice column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7) to the single `Task List` for `Task Phase`.  Your workflow should then set that value to the appropriate phase at the same time it is creating the tasks and setting the `New Hire Lookup`.

You could create a separate [View](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) for each New Hire per phase, however, it would probably be easier to use [dynamic url list filters](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html), then you can send the link to a dynamically filtered view from your workflow in an email -- or you could even add a Hyperlink column on your `New Hire List` that the workflow could populate with a link the current phase's dynamically filtered view.  For example, if your New Hire Lookup column is named `TaskNewHire` and your Phase column is named `TaskOnboardingPhase` then your workflow would construct a URL that looks like `https://mysharepointserver/sites/onboardingsite/NewHireTasks/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=TaskNewHire%5Fx003a%5FID&FilterValue1=<<InsertIDOfCurrentNewHireHere>>&FilterField2=TaskOnboardingPhase&FilterValue2=<<InsertTitleOfCurrentPhaseHere>>`

Comment: Is there a way to assign multiple users (that are pulled from Active Directory) to a single task? That way if I have 4 new hires, they all have the same task list?

Comment: Yes, you can, and I don't know exactly what types of tasks you are making, but as a general rule of thumb, if you assign a task to more than one person, then no one ends up doing it.  From a process standpoint, task assignments work best when each task is assigned to a single individual.  With that said, if you go into the list settings, then click to edit the settings of the AssignedTo field, you can change it to allow multiple users.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but these are "Onboarding tasks" that every new employee has to do. So I'm trying to have a "Dashboard" where the new employee can go and see all of "their" tasks. Even though each new employee will have the same set of tasks.

Comment: But if you assign multiple users to the same task, none of them could ever mark it as complete because it would then show complete for everyone.  At that point, it would be better to use a custom list with a multi-user column and a description without any of the status and percent complete fields that come with a Task list.

Comment: Yeah I ended up creating a list that just has like 30 Yes/No Click box columns with a person column lolz.